# Django Many-To-One

Tags: django, one-to-many

I'm trying to create a simple to-do app in Django. I have some trouble to understand the idea of foreign keys. Each project suppose to get multiple apartments, and each apartment should get multiple tasks.

models:

```
# Project model
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(_("City"), max_length=30)
    street = models.CharField(_("Street"), max_length=30)
    number = models.IntegerField(_("Number"), max_length=4)
    ZIP = models.ImageField(_("ZIP"), max_length=10)
    manager = models.CharField(_("Manager"), choices=managers, default='ariel')

    # Apartments
    apartment = models.ForeignKey(_("Apartment"), Apartment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)


# Apartment model
class Apartment(models.Model):
    building = models.CharField(_("Building"), max_length=4)
    floor = models.CharField(_("Floor"), max_length=4)
    number = models.CharField(_("Number"), max_length=4)
    type = models.CharField(_("Type"), max_length=4)
    upgraded = models.BooleanField(_("Upgraded"), default=False)
    drawing = models.FileField(_("Drawing"), upload_to=None)
    notes = models.TextField(_("Notes"), max_length=500)
    status = models.BooleanField(_("Completed"), default=False)

    # Tasks
    airTunnels = models.ForeignKey(_("Air Tunnels"), Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gasPipelines = models.ForeignKey(_("Gas Pipelines"), Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.number, self.status)

# Task model
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_("Task"), max_length=30)
    doneBy = models.CharField(_("Done By"), choices=workers, default='daniel')
    date = models.DateTimeField(_("Date"), default=timezone.now())

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.title)
```

Comment: If many apartments can belong to a single project, you need a foreignkey on `Apartment` to `Project`. And the same goes for tasks: if many tasks can belong to a single apartment, you need a foreignkey on `Task` to `Apartment`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `apartment = models.ForeignKey(_("Apartment"), Apartment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`, it means that each project has onyl one apartment. So you must define different project for each apartment. If your each apartment can has only one project, you must define foreignkey inside your apartment model like that:

```
class Apartment(models.Model):
    #...your other fields
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

For apartment tasks, If I understood correctly, your apartment model can has multiple tasks.So, you can use ManyToMany field for this.With this definition, your each apartment can has multiple tasks. But your each task can belong to multiple apartment objects. If you don't want to each task can belongs to different apartment objects, you must set OneToMany relation.You can do that with adding foreignkeyfield to task model like that:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    #...your other fields
    apartment = models.ForeignKey(Apartment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: About the project - apartment - got it. About the tasks - each apartment has a set of tasks. 'task name - done by - date' ect. Not all types of apartments has the same set of tasks, but it pretty much the same. What will be the best way to preform that?

Comment: A apartment has different tasks but each task belongs to one apartment, am i right?

Comment: there are couple of tasks, that goes repeatedly for each apartment.
'Gas pipelines - Done By - Date'
'Air Tunnels - Done By - Date'
and so on.
Each apartment has her own combination of the tasks from the list, it depeneding on her type.

Comment: Ok, you needs many to many relationship between apartment and task then.So you can add `tasks = models.ManyToManyField(Task)` to your Apartment model and remove `apartment = models.ForeignKey(Apartment)` from Task model

Comment: I've took your advice and did Many to Many, and now I see the list of the task in each apartment I add. But now I can not give separate time signature to each apartment for each task.